# Trigger Jenkins job on even calender dates

Tags: jenkins

I have 2 jobs one of which I would wish to run only on even calendar days like 2, 4, 6, 8 ... of a month & the other job should run only on odd days.

Any idea how to schedule this in Jenkins?

Thanks In Advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use builtin option called `poll scm` in Jenkins job configuration page. You can specify cron like expression to tell Jenkins when it should poll you code repository and build your project.\

Syntax would look like this [syntax taken from here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16093/how-can-i-tell-cron-to-run-a-command-every-other-day-odd-even) :

```
# Will only run on odd days:
0 0 1-31/2 * * command

# Will only run on even days:
0 0 2-30/2 * * command
```

Comment: Perfect! just what I was looking for! Thanks!